# Select columns in panda's dataframe that have an integer header

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in pandas that looks like this:

```
   100  200  300  400
0    1    1    0    1
1    1    1    1    0
```

What I want to do is select specific columns from this data frame. But when I try the following code (the df_matrix being the dataframe displayed at the top) :

```
intermediary_df = df_matrix["100"]
```

It does not work and from what I can tell is because it is an integer. I tried to force it with str(100) but gave the same error as before:

```
File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 958, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
TypeError: an integer is required

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "A:\python project\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3078, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 164, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
KeyError: '100'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 958, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
TypeError: an integer is required

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "A:/python project/testing/testing4.py", line 42, in <module>
    intermediary_df = df_matrix["100"]
  File "A:\python project\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2688, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "A:\python project\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2695, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "A:\python project\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2489, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "A:\python project\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4115, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "A:\python project\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3080, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 164, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
KeyError: '100'
```

Does anyone know how to get around this? Thanks!

**EDIT 1:**

After trying to use `intermediary_df = df_matrix[100]` it worked as expecte. Btw, if someone else is facing this problem and wants to select multiple columns at the same time, you can use:

```
intermediary_df = df_matrix[[100, 300]]
```

and the output will be:

```
   100  300
0    1    0
1    1    1
```

Comment: Print your columns df_matrix.columns, check it is int or str

Comment: Try `intermediary_df = df_matrix[100]` ?

Comment: @W-B it seems to be integers. Output from console `Int64Index([100, 200, 300, 400], dtype='int64')`

Comment: So try , df_matrix[100]

Comment: @harvpan it worked now. Thank you!

Comment: @W-B it works, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use below as in this case as your columns are `int` .

```
intermediary_df = df_matrix[100]`
```

If you want your columns to be accessed as `str`, Use:

`df.columns = [str(x) for x in df.columns]`

and then

`df['100']`

Output

```
0    1
1    1
Name: 100, dtype: int64
```

Comment: do you know how I can apply filters on columns with integer headers? I have tried `df_matrix[df_matrix.100 == 1]` , but that results into an error...

Comment: Just use `df_matrix.loc[df_matrix[100] == 1]`

Comment: No problem. @Adrian. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I think your column type is an integer,
but if it's not try this using `DataFrame.loc`

*Example:*

```
intermediary_df = df_matrix.loc[:,100]
```

or

```
intermediary_df = df_matrix.iloc[:,0]
```

Comment: The code did not work but using intermediary_df = df_matrix[100] makes it work